# Cannot see sqlite as a Data Source after installation in VS2013

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I just downloaded the SQLite to my VS2013, I have a winform project and wanted to added as a datasource, however, the option for SQLite does not appear. I downloaded through Extensions and Updates in VS 2013. I tried adding as a reference from my project as well and there was no SQLite reference available.

I tried installing SQLite again, and it said that it was already installed, but I cannot see references anywhere.

Did I miss something? This is the first time I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get designer support for SQLite in Visual Studio, you have to download a very specific version of System.Data.SQLite. The downloads page has an astonishing 56 different possibilities, so it's easy to get the wrong one.

Look for the big bold text that says this:

> This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components
>   for Visual Studio 2013.

But it's still easy to miss among the zillions of downloads. If you need to, use Control-F to find the "Visual Studio 2013" text.